# dirname vs. providing root path for sendFile() Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm following a tutorial on the MEAN stack, but it's a bit old and some of the methods the author uses are deprecated. He uses sendfile() and I changed it to sendFile() because the server was giving me warnings about sendfile() being deprecated. The new sendFile() says it takes an absolute path as opposed to a relative one. I had an endpoint which worked:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + 'layouts/posts.html')
})
```

in the server, but now we're breaking all the endpoints out into controllers. The current (relevant) file structure looks like this:

/controllers/static.js

/layouts/posts.html

The tutorial says the endpoint in /controllers is supposed to look like this:

```
var router = require('express').Router()

router.get('/', function (req, res){
    res.sendFile('layouts/posts.html')
})

module.exports = router
```

with this corresponding code in the server:

```
app.use(require('./controllers/static'))
```

With ('layouts/post.html') I get the error "path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile" and when I try to add __dirname or a path from the server root, I get an ENOENT ...../controllers/somethingItried/posts.html. Can someone explain the best way to fix this and what the server is considering the absolute path here? My attempts to make a path from root have failed:

../layouts/posts.html

as well as the suggestions from this page:

[node.js TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile [failed to parse JSON]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079611/node-js-typeerror-path-must-be-absolute-or-specify-root-to-res-sendfile-failed)

Answer (score 0):

Add root path to the next parameter 'options'
like:

```
res.sendFile('layouts/posts.html', {root: __dirname});
```