# Heroku - prevent starting

Tags: heroku

I have a dyno on Heroku I use for one off jobs. I do not want it to "start". I added this in my Procfile:

```
heroku scale web=0
```

However it still tries to start every few hours as my log show:

```
=== web (Hobby): `npm start`
web.1: crashed 2015/09/29 07:28:12 (~ 4h ago)
```

How can I address this?  When I searched for the solution the above Procfile entry was suggested.

Comment: Do you have a `web` process specified in your Procfile? (if you don't want a web process, you should not have a web process in your Procfile.)