# How to stop Heroku from trying to start script with `npm start`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, npm, scheduled-tasks

I am building a server-based application that runs a series of automated scripts (i.e., "bots") in the cloud. I have provisioned an instance of Heroku Scheduler to automatically run one of those scripts as shown in the below Fig. 1.

Fig. 1. Screen capture of Heroku Scheduler dashboard

[image]

As you can see from Fig. 1., the scheduler is supposed to run the following command

```
node src/spiders/clusters/auctionMacro.js
```

every ten minutes. Which appears to be happening as expected as shown below in Fig 2. which shows the complete log output.

The five log entries beginning at 2020-01-12T10:41:54.171208+00:00 appear to confirm the expected command of `node src/spiders/clusters/auctionMacro.js` is happening as expected and the script is executing as expected.

However, the following three log entries indicate that the scheduler is also trying to run the command `npm start` and causing the script to crash.

> 2020-01-12T11:00:13.464651+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
>   
> 2020-01-12T11:00:15.143335+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
>   
> 2020-01-12T11:00:15.080831+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start

What can I do about this? Can I turn off the `npm start` command somehow? Or do something else to correct the issue and prevent the script from crashing?

The full log output generated by `heroku logs` is as follows.

Fig 2. Complete output of `$ heroku logs`

> 2020-01-12T10:41:46.690564+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `node src/spiders/clusters/auctionMacro.js` by user scheduler@addons.heroku.com
>   
> 2020-01-12T10:41:54.171208+00:00 heroku[scheduler.2053]: Starting process with command `node src/spiders/clusters/auctionMacro.js`
>   
> 2020-01-12T10:41:54.864597+00:00 heroku[scheduler.2053]: State changed from starting to up
>   
> 2020-01-12T10:41:56.797007+00:00 app[scheduler.2053]: [Successful script log]
>   
> 2020-01-12T10:41:56.799138+00:00 app[scheduler.2053]: [Successful script log]
>   
> 2020-01-12T10:41:56.799853+00:00 app[scheduler.2053]: [Successful script log]
>   
> 2020-01-12T10:41:56.893782+00:00 app[scheduler.2053]: [Successful script log]
>   
> 2020-01-12T10:41:59.126489+00:00 heroku[scheduler.2053]: State changed from up to complete
>   
> 2020-01-12T10:41:59.111484+00:00 heroku[scheduler.2053]: Process exited with status 0
>   
> 2020-01-12T10:49:21.119405+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `node src/spiders/clusters/auctionMacro.js` by user myemail@example.com
>   
> 2020-01-12T10:49:29.862904+00:00 heroku[run.9372]: State changed from starting to up
>   
> 2020-01-12T10:49:29.827990+00:00 heroku[run.9372]: Awaiting client
>   
> 2020-01-12T10:49:29.878338+00:00 heroku[run.9372]: Starting process with command `node src/spiders/clusters/auctionMacro.js`
>   
> 2020-01-12T11:00:05.438362+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
>   
> 2020-01-12T11:00:13.464651+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
>   
> 2020-01-12T11:00:15.143335+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
>   
> 2020-01-12T11:00:15.080831+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
>   
> 2020-01-12T11:00:15.088306+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   
> 2020-01-12T11:00:15.088587+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   
> 2020-01-12T11:00:15.088690+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-01-12T11_00_15_081Z-debug.log
>   
> 2020-01-12T11:00:15.130770+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
>   
> 2020-01-12T11:08:51.893315+00:00 heroku[run.9372]: Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
>   
> 2020-01-12T11:08:52.437813+00:00 heroku[run.9372]: State changed from up to complete
>   
> 2020-01-12T11:08:52.421870+00:00 heroku[run.9372]: Process exited with status 129
>   
> me@My-MacBook-Air puppeteer % heroku maint
>   
> 2020-01-12T22:15:01.428118+00:00 app[scheduler.9940]: == Start: 2020-01-12 22:04:21.402
>   
> 2020-01-12T22:15:01.428167+00:00 app[scheduler.9940]: 
>   
> 2020-01-12T22:15:02.410217+00:00 heroku[scheduler.9940]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
>   
> 2020-01-12T22:15:02.481455+00:00 heroku[scheduler.9940]: Process exited with status 143.929 (running for 10.7 minutes)

Edit:

[Based on this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32168011), I ran the following command

```
heroku scale web=0
```

And received the following response in the terminal

> Scaling dynos... done, now running web at 0:Free

I'm not sure what that means or if this is the direction I should be heading.

Answer (score 0):

The solution had two parts for me. I solved the problem after implementing both parts.

Firstly, I had to turn off the `npm start` with the following terminal command as indicated in the edit to the OP.

```
heroku scale web=0
```

Secondly, I had to configure my buildpacks and `puppeteer.launch()` options to support running in the Heroku server environment as follows.

> First, I clear all my buildpacks and then I added the puppeteer-heroku-buildpack and the heroku/nodejs one:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:clear
$ heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack
$ heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs
```

> Then, add the following args to the puppeteer launch function:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  args : [
    '--no-sandbox',
    '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
  ],
});
```

> Finally, deploy it back to Heroku:

```sh
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Fixing deployment issue"
$ git push heroku master
```

[The source of this second item is this SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55090914/1640892)