# using node js express to open up html page

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to node js express. I am trying to open a html page at location D:\d3 project\index12.htm.
The app.js is at location D:\d3 project\project_part1\project_part1\app.js

```
app.use(express.static('D:\d3 project')); 
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile('D:/d3 project' + '/'+'index12.html'); 
});
var server = app.listen(3001, '0.0.0.0', function () {
console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

I am getting this error

```
TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile
at ServerResponse.sendFile (D:\d3 project\project_part1\project_part1\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:403:11)
at D:\d3 project\project_part1\project_part1\app.js:10:9
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\d3 project\project_part1\project_part1\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (D:\d3 project\project_part1\project_part1\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
at Route.dispatch (D:\d3 project\project_part1\project_part1\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\d3 project\project_part1\project_part1\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at D:\d3 project\project_part1\project_part1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
at Function.process_params (D:\d3 project\project_part1\project_part1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
at next (D:\d3 project\project_part1\project_part1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
at SendStream.error (D:\d3 project\project_part1\project_part1\node_modules\express\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:120:7)
```

I suppose I am giving the absolute path and not the relative path..

**Solution:**
just changed the code to

```
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../../index12.html'));
```

and add

```
var path = require('path');
```

Comment: Following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079611/node-js-typeerror-path-must-be-absolute-or-specify-root-to-res-sendfile-failed will help you.

Comment: Thank you. But i do not want to link it through _dirname.. is there any option of using ../ to go back 2 folders?

Comment: you should always link it through __dirname. Given that when you deploy your code on some other machine, the rest of the folder structure would not be under your control, while your application's folder structure would remain under your control.

Comment: Also, you are using path.join incorrectly. You could write `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../index12.html'))` and let `path` module take care of leading and trailing slashes.

Comment: alright.. tried dat....thank u..