# Can't precisely decipher error: TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile at ServerResponse.sendFile

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux, passport.js

I am a react/redux/mongoose/passport noob. I assume it should send the response back through axios and to the react page, but it appears thats not what's happening.

I'm getting this really odd error that's similar to the question found at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079611/node-js-typeerror-path-must-be-absolute-or-specify-root-to-res-sendfile-failed).

```
GET /robots.txt 500 6.666 ms - 2143
TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile
at ServerResponse.sendFile (/Users/eric/Documents/todobuild/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:421:11)
at /Users/eric/Documents/todobuild/server.js:40:12
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/eric/Documents/todobuild/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/Users/eric/Documents/todobuild/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (/Users/eric/Documents/todobuild/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/eric/Documents/todobuild/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /Users/eric/Documents/todobuild/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
at param (/Users/eric/Documents/todobuild/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:354:14)
at param (/Users/eric/Documents/todobuild/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
at Function.process_params (/Users/eric/Documents/todobuild/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:410:3)
at next (/Users/eric/Documents/todobuild/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at SessionStrategy.strategy.pass (/Users/eric/Documents/todobuild/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:338:9)
at SessionStrategy.authenticate (/Users/eric/Documents/todobuild/node_modules/passport/lib/strategies/session.js:75:10)
at attempt (/Users/eric/Documents/todobuild/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:361:16)
at authenticate (/Users/eric/Documents/todobuild/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:362:7)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/eric/Documents/todobuild/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

From what I gather, the difference between our situations is that they were getting the error upon starting up their node server, but mine starts fine. It's only after I set up my first API request that I started having this problem.

**The problem script is as follows:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const User = require('../../models/user.js');

module.exports = function(app) {

app.post('/api/login', function(request, response) {
  User.findOne({ email: request.body.email })
    .then(function(data) {
      if (data.email) {
        passport.authenticate('local')(request, response, () => {
          if (request.user) {
            return response.send(JSON.stringify(request.user));
          }
        });
      }

      return response.send(JSON.stringify({ error: 'There was an error logging in.'}));
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
});
```

**Here is also my server.js file for good measure.**

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const logger = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const expressSession = require('express-session')({
  secret: 'some random string',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
});

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/todo', {useMongoClient: true 
});
const db = mongoose.connection;
//models
const User = require('./models/user');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.text());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' }));
app.use(expressSession);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

//routes
require('./routes/api/api-routes.js')(app);

app.get('*', function(request, response) {
  response.sendFile('index.html');
});

db.on('error', function(error) {
  console.log('Mongoose Error: ', error);
});

db.once('open', function() {
  console.log('Mongoose connection successful.');
});

app.listen(PORT, 'localhost', function() {
  console.log('App running on port 3000');
});
```

**Dependencies**

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-import-export": "^1.0.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "express": "^4.16.1",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "mongoose": "^4.12.0",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-local-mongoose": "^4.2.1",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0"
  }
```

Again, I apologize for my ignorance. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace says this:

> at /Users/eric/Documents/todobuild/server.js:40:12

So the problem is line 40 in `server.js`. An educated guess suggests that line 40 is this line:

```
response.sendFile('index.html');
```

Docs for `sendFile` are here:

https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile

The key thing is that you're using the relative file path `index.html` but `sendFile` needs an absolute path, e.g.:

```
response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
```