# Why do I get an error when I serve a static file for two routes in node.js using sendFile() method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I tried to send a static html file for two routes '/' and '/test'.
It is working for '/' route but not '/test'/

I am getting following error:

```
TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile
    at ServerResponse.sendFile (E:\sairam\javascript\node\Node middleware\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:421:11)
    at E:\sairam\javascript\node\Node middleware\index.js:11:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\sairam\javascript\node\Node middleware\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (E:\sairam\javascript\node\Node middleware\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (E:\sairam\javascript\node\Node middleware\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\sairam\javascript\node\Node middleware\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at E:\sairam\javascript\node\Node middleware\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (E:\sairam\javascript\node\Node middleware\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (E:\sairam\javascript\node\Node middleware\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at SendStream.error (E:\sairam\javascript\node\Node middleware\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:121:7)
```

### This is my app.js

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile('index.html');
    res.end();
})
app.get('/test', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile('index.html');
    res.end();
})
app.listen(3000);
```

index.html file is in public folder.. that was am serving as static container.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node.js TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile \[failed to parse JSON\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079611/node-js-typeerror-path-must-be-absolute-or-specify-root-to-res-sendfile-failed)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use relative paths for [res.sendFile](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile), you need to specify the root option. Use the following code to serve `index.html`, assuming it resides in the same directory as the Node app source.

You can get the current directory with [__dirname](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname).

```js
app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile('index.html',{root:__dirname});
})
app.get('/test', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile('index.html',{root:__dirname});
})
```

Please also reference [node.js TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile [failed to parse JSON]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079611/node-js-typeerror-path-must-be-absolute-or-specify-root-to-res-sendfile-failed)

(Thank you to Saurabh Mistry for the reference)

Answer (score 0):

try this way :

```
app.get(['/','test'], function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/'+ 'index.html');
});
```