# Accessing local path using node server

Tags: node.js

### In below code i can able to listen port 9080 but i need to access my local file path (D:\xampp\htdocs\ln\try\index.html) using http request

```
var http = require('http');

const PORT=9080; 

function handleRequest(request, response){
    response.end('It Works!! Path Hit: ' + request.url);
}

var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);

  server.listen(PORT, function(){
    //Callback triggered when server is successfully listening. Hurray!
    console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:%s", PORT);
});
```

Comment: are you after __filename?

Comment: All i need is to access my local path files using server with nodejs

Comment: You need to be more specific. Do you want to require files into your index.html? Do you want to read files into your app or do you just want to actual path?
__filename may be what your after or I may be misunderstanding your question.
https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_filename

Comment: i want to access path like this http://localhost/pp/login.html

Comment: i want to run my html files as http://localhost:9080/example/index.html request instead of D:example/index.html

Comment: Currently i am opening file as this file:///D:/xampp/htdocs/ln/try/index.html  where as i want to open as httpL//localhost:9080/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

installing http-server using node as ( npm install http-server -g ).
When you add globally this node module you can run server from any where in your path.

[image: Run server any where in the computer as below shown image]

Answer (score -2):

How to serve a html file with node...
[Loading basic HTML in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720343/loading-basic-html-in-node-js)

You read the html file in with the fs module then create the http server, on requests you write the html to the response and then end the response.

Its much easier though if you get express.
[Render basic HTML view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529586/render-basic-html-view-in-node-js-express)

Comment: i am not asking for only html file any path in server. i think this helps you understand