# How to open the site in a browser tab after running gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am a new to gulp and I am working in Gulpfile.js where I have this so far

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  gulp.src('public/stylesheets/style.scss')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/stylesheets'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('public/stylesheets/*.scss', ['sass']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'watch']);
```

when I run `$ gulp` nothing happens, and I want a gulp file which responds to the gulp command and opens the page in the browser.

There is the I have my folders:

[image]

Which is the proper task to accomplish what I want?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var open = require('gulp-open');


// Default usage: 
// Open one file with default application 

gulp.task('open', function(){
  gulp.src('./index.html')
  .pipe(open());
});
```

Comment: so I need to install those modules? `os` and `gulp-open`?

Comment: Well you also need to configure the options. Choose what kind of task you would like: npmjs.com/package/gulp-open

Comment: I did it now, but it is opening only a file `file:///Users/Marcelo/Documents/Projects/showstracker/public/index.html` I need it to open something like localhost:3000 in the browser

Comment: you have to use an absolute path. 

```var options = {
  uri: 'localhost:3000',
  app: '/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app'
};
gulp.src('./')
  .pipe(open(options));```

Comment: How to open my index.html page after I run npm start?

Comment: @RohitSingh You would need to do so with node using `readFile`

See this for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720343/loading-basic-html-in-node-js