# Is there a way to edit my files through an admin panel

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

So I am making a forum software. I would like it so users can edit the HTML part of the code on there own through an admin panel. What would be the best way to do this?

I am currently trying it with a database but in my opinion, it takes up too much space and is a lot of hassle to do.

I would like a way so I can directly edit my HTML code through the browser.

Comment: You could [write the HTML contents to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js) and then [load that file into the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720343/loading-basic-html-in-node-js). But in my opinion, using a database to store the content is the most effective method.

Comment: What you are looking for is called a CMS. (content management system). There are few CMS already out there, if you are looking for an easy solution , try WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion,you should post your HTML code to the backend,and call the backend service just like Node.js/php/java to rewrite your HTML file on the service side.